# Can Android events "switch" within a single thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm a little bit confused and would like to confirm that my understanding of how threads work in Android is correct.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understand Android events(button clicks, touch events, etc) are put on the main thread in a queue as they are fired, and then handled in the order they came.

However, if the handlers for these events takes very long, is it possible that the thread will put it back to the end of the queue to continue at a later time, or is it guaranteed that the events will be completed in the same order they come?

In other words, if I am currently in method A, and then onClick gets called(not from method A), then A will always finish before onClick gets to start.

The reason I ask is I need to know whether I need to synchronize the variables even though there is only a single thread accessing them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's guaranteed. If code is executing in the UI thread, it cannot be interrupted to run other code in the same thread.

(That's why, when applications do too much work in the UI thread, *Application Not Responding* happens -- messages are not processed because the thread is doing something else).

Comment: That's what I figured but I didn't see it explicitly stated anywhere in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any method executing on the main thread will run to completion before anything else queued on the main thread will be executed.